# scroll horizontally with uiscrollview completely through storyboard & autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout, storyboard

I feel very dense for asking this but I have tried several solutions and have not been able to come up with my desired outcome. I have 2 UIViews which are subviews of a larger UIView that is the subview of a scrollView. These two views are the login & signup screens respectively and the user may swipe between them to appropriately access the app. However for some reason the scrollview will not scroll horizontally between these two views. The sample I'm looking at uses not code to achieve this and I have mimicked the constraints exactly. This may sound dumb but does anyone have any suggestions on how I may achieve this horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 3):

"*I have 2 UIViews which are subviews of a larger UIView that is the subview of a scrollView*"

OK, let's say there is Sub1 and Sub2, inside a ContainerView (call it CV), which is inside a ScrollView (SV).

In Interface Builder:

- Sub1 and Sub2 each are 300-width
- CV should be 600-width, to hold Sub1 and Sub2 side-by-side
- SV width should be 300 - you will see only Sub1

In order for the ScrollView to scroll, its content width must be greater than its own width. If you set the Leading and Trailing constraints on CV to be relative to SV, that will define the content width.

It sounds like your "ContainerView" constraints are *not* set to the ScrollView

Hope it's ok to have these images here... anyway...

SV - ScrollView - is blue

CV - Container View - is pink

Sub1 and Sub2 are yellow

Start with a Scroll View, 300 x 300 and centered both directions:

[image]

Add a UIView - this will be CV - into the SV, at 8,8 with default size of 240 x 128 (we will change that immediately), and add Leading and Top constraints of 8 each:

[image]

Change the width and height of the CV to 600 x 120, and set the width and height constraints. Half of the view now extends to the right, beyond the edge of the SV:

[image]

Add two subviews to the CV - for demo, I used UILabels. Set their width x height to 50 x 30, and position Sub1 at 8,8.

[image]

Give Sub1 Left, Top (8,8) and Width and Height (50x30) constraints. That will keep it "pinned" at the top-left of the CV:

[image]

Give Sub2 Width and Height (50x30) constraints, and Bottom and Right/Trailing constraints of 8,8. When you've set those constraints, click the "Update Frames" button to auto-move the Sub2 label into place - "pinned" to the bottom-right corner of the CV (no longer in view in IB):

[image]

Now the real key part: give the CV Right/Trailing and Bottom constraints of 8 each. This is what auto-layout uses to determine the ContentSize of the SV. If you run the app, you should now be able to scroll horizontally from  Sub1 to Sub2.

[image]

Assuming that has all worked, you can play around with adjusting the Width and Height constraints of CV to see how it affects the scrolling.

Source code here: https://github.com/DonMag/ScrollViewConstraints

Hope that helps :)

Comment: yes I believe this is the issue. But I am still perplexed by your use of language here. When you say "relative to SV", are you suggesting stacking the SV & CV together & then setting their leading and trailing edges?

Comment: ok, or if you had a site with similar info i would be happy to explore that as well

Comment: Sorry - out of time today... I can clarify it for you tomorrow.

Comment: hello, all of this makes sense except for the final screen. For CV if size is 2x that of the SV why would I set the RT trailing constraint to 8? This does not make sense to me

Comment: The right-most trailing constraint is what sets the ContentSize width, and the bottom-most constraint sets the ContentSize height - so setting it to 8 gives it an 8-pt "buffer". It could just as easily - or more likely - be set to 0 all the way around. This becomes more evident when you have multiple subviews in the SV, instead of a single "ContainerView" that holds subviews.

Comment: If you haven't gotten this working yet, I put up a repo you can play around with here (I'm assuming Xcode 8): https://github.com/DonMag/ScrollViewConstraints